# How to use percentage instead of ProgressBar control in VB.NET BackgroundWorker

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I just want to report `ProgressChanged` while executing the `DoWork` method

My code is this:

```
Private Sub CloudDataWorker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles CloudDataWorker.DoWork
        GlobalVartions.PushtoCloud()
        CloudDataWorker.ReportProgress(100, "")
End Sub
```

What I have done so far is this that doesn't work.

```
Private Sub CloudDataWorker_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles CloudDataWorker.ProgressChanged
        uploadStat.Text = "Uploading" & "%"
End Sub
```

Instead of using a `Progressbar`, I want to use a `percentage %` as an indicator.

How can I achieve this ? Thanks.

Comment: The example in the [BackgroundWorker Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.7.2) shows exactly that.

Comment: If the "GlobalVartions" class cannot tell you how the PushtoCloud() function is progressing then you can't meaningfully call ReportProgress either.   There is somebody that can make that class better, you won't him here.

Comment: @HansPassant I solve my problem . . my answer below . . Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After too many attempts, I have done the following with this code

This is my `DoWork` Method

```
Private Sub CloudDataWorker_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles CloudDataWorker.DoWork

        Dim i As Integer = 1
        Do While (i <= 10)
            If (CloudDataWorker.CancellationPending = True) Then
                e.Cancel = True
                Exit Do
            Else
                GlobalVartions.PushtoCloud()
                CloudDataWorker.ReportProgress((i * 2))
            End If

            i = (i + 1)
        Loop

End Sub
```

And my `ProgressChanged` Method

```
Private Sub CloudDataWorker_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles CloudDataWorker.ProgressChanged
        uploadStat.Text = (e.ProgressPercentage.ToString + "%")
    End Sub
```

Now it works great . .

Comment: @F0r3v3r-A-N00b That was supposed to be 10, I updated the answer to 2 and notice the i = (i + 1), so its find.

Comment: Does that actually make sense though?  In your original code you were calling `GlobalVartions.PushtoCloud` and now you're calling it 10 times.  Do you really want to call it 10 times?  I seriously doubt it.

Comment: to get the percentage: (i/10)*100

Comment: @jmcilhinney yep . . for duplication.

Answer (score 1):

In you ProgressChanged method, the 'e' parameter holds the percentage value in  [e.ProgressPercentage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.progresschangedeventargs.progresspercentage?view=netframework-4.7.2)

So you just have to load it like this:

```
uploadStat.Text = "Uploading" & e.ProgressPercentage & "%"
```